# OpenScript error: Script section: Unspecified. java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: id_ecPublicKey

Tags: openscript

We are trying to use OpenScript to generate load test for OATS. The script will call `org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter` for authentication. We are getting following error in the script:

```
10:22:56,860 ERROR [1] Error in section Unspecified at line unknown. 
       ScriptException occured. 
       An unexpected exception occurred in the script. 
       Script section: Unspecified.

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: id_ecPublicKey
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.signing.internal.PEMFileRSAPrivateKeySupplier.<init>(PEMFileRSAPrivateKeySupplier.java:46)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.signing.internal.DefaultRequestSignerFactory.createKeySupplier(DefaultRequestSignerFactory.java:108)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.signing.internal.DefaultRequestSignerFactory.createRequestSigner(DefaultRequestSignerFactory.java:51)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.<init>(ObjectStorageClient.java:98)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.<init>(ObjectStorageClient.java:73)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.<init>(ObjectStorageClient.java:59)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.<init>(ObjectStorageClient.java:48)
    at script.run(script.java:38)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.IteratingVUser.run(IteratingVUser.java:353)
    at oracle.oats.scripting.modules.basic.api.internal.IteratingAgent.run(IteratingAgent.java:801)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has anyone seen same kind of issue before?

This error only happens when the project is created as script. If we created the project as generic Java project it works fine. Our guess is when using script there are some lib mismatch which caused it to use id_ecPublicKey.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too. It's from a jar file conflict.

When I exclude some dependences relative to "org.bouncycastle", like the below Maven code, then the error goes away.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.rapid-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>rapid-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```